# Code recognition by JVM

Tags: jvm

Will there be any difference in the bytecode or the compiled code using different JDKs(eg: 1.4 & 1.5 in this case). If so, how would a JVM recognize and address it at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The class file format has version information in it.

See the [Java class file format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html). The `major_version` and `minor_version` fields are used to differentiate different versions of class files.

And yes, there can be differences. For instance, JDK1.4 didn't support generics. It couldn't load classes that contain them (produced by a 1.5 compiler).